# CMake ENV variable only accepts a single value

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new to CMake. I'm trying to create a list of C++ source files, and build an executable using those source files. To that avoid passing the list one level at a time, I am using an environment variable. However, not all listed sources are added to the env var, only the first one is.

Here's what I have:

Directory structure:

```
<root>
├─ build
│  ├─ <snip>
├─ src
│  ├─ something
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  ├─ a.cpp
│  │  ├─ a.h
│  │  ├─ b.cpp
│  │  └─ b.h
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  └─ main.cpp
├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

root/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(samplecpp VERSION "0.1.0" LANGUAGES CXX)

# ---- SOURCES ----

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

set(ENV{MY_SOURCES} "")

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

message(STATUS "MY_SOURCES = " $ENV{MY_SOURCES})

# ---- EXECUTABLE ----

add_executable(samplecpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp $ENV{MY_SOURCES})
```

root/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(something)
```

root/src/something/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(
    ENV{MY_SOURCES}
    $ENV{MY_SOURCES}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/b.cpp
)
```

Running cmake should print the message `MY_SOURCES = root/src/something/a.cpproot/src/something/b.cpp`, but I only get `MY_SOURCES = root/src/something/a.cpp`. Because of this, `cmake --build` fails with this error:

```
<root>/src/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `B::do_b()'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just in case, [here's the sample on github](https://github.com/jprochazk/cmake-cpp-sample)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/set.html), but setting an **environment** variable accepts only a **single** value:

```
set(ENV{name} value)
```

Before 3.14 version CMake **silently ignores** other values.

Since 3.14 version CMake emits a **warning** when more than one values are passed:

> Only the first value argument is used when setting an environment variable.

Source: [Source/cmSetCommand.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.14.0/Source/cmSetCommand.cxx)

---

It is still possible to assign a list to the environment variable by using its **semicolon-separated string** representation:

```
# Don't work: assigns only 'a' and emits warning in CMake 4.14+
set(ENV{MY_SOURCES} a b c)
# Works: assign list of 'a', 'b', 'c' elements
set(ENV{MY_SOURCES} "a;b;c")
# The same but using intermediate CMake variable
set(MY_SOURCES_TMP a b c)
set(ENV{MY_SOURCES} "${MY_SOURCES_TMP}")
```

Comment: makes me wonder why they wouldn't document such an important piece of info, or whether there's any reason for there to be this limit in the first place. thank you!